# Parent Child Issue in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I have Parent component where I am setting up the state, calling the child component, taking up the value from child and sending it to parent again and setting the value.

```
class Parent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            value: ""
        };
    }

    emailList = [
        {
            label: "Alen Musk",
            text: "Alen@email.com"
        },
        {
            label: "John smith",
            text: "john@email.com"
        },
        {
            label: "Jacky shroff",
            text: "jacky@email.com"
        },
        {
            label: "Bruce wayne",
            text: "Bruce@email.com"
        }
    ];

    onInputChange(value) {
        this.setState({ value: value });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                             
                    <InputSuggestionsComponent
                        label="Email"
                        value={this.state.value}
                        typeaheadItems={this.emailList} 
                        lookupKey="text" 
                        onChange={this.onInputChange}
                    />
                
               
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Parent;
```

Child Component :

```js
<Field
    onFocus={this.setFocus}
    onBlur={this.onBlurHandler}
    onKeyDown={this.onKeyDown}
    disabled={this.props.disabled}
    value={this.props.value}
    onChange={this.changeHandler}
    onSelect={this.onSelectHandler}
    required
    name={label}
    type={fieldType}
    textColor={currentTheme.text}
    buttonMovable={this.props.type === "password"}
/>

changeHandler = e => {
  this.props.onChange(e.target.value);
  this.checkTypeAhead(this.props.value);
};

setTypeAhead = value => {
    console.log("props value in settypeahead", this.props.value);
    console.log(" value in settypeahead", value);
    const {
        typeaheadItems,
        lookupKey
    } = this.props;
    this.setState({
        showSuggestions: true,
        selectedIndex: null,
        suggestions: typeaheadItems.filter(
          item => (lookupKey ? item[lookupKey] : item).toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) === 0
        )
    });
};


checkTypeAhead(value) {
    //console.log("check for typeahead ", this.props);
    if (this.props.typeaheadItems && this.props.lookupKey) {
        this.setTypeAhead();
    }
    this.props.onChange(value);
}
```

Now What happens my child `onChange` handler gets called where I take the value from `e.target.value` and send to parent to update in `this.state.props` and after that opens my suggestion list.

But as for the first time , I get `this.props.value` as "" as it has been set in parent.
What to do if I want to take up the value as the use types in ?

For Example : if the user types  "a ", I should get "a", in `this.props.value`.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the problem with your code. I made a snippet on which you can replicate your issue. here https://codesandbox.io/s/ovzm69nkyz

Comment: @MadeOfAir : ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that state updating is asynchronous. So when you do

```
this.props.onChange(e.target.value);
this.checkTypeAhead(this.props.value);
```

the second line does not receive the updated parent state as that has not yet occurred.

A solution could be to use the [`componentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) lifecycle event, on your child component, so you can do the `checkTypeAhead` only **after** you receive the new props from the parent component.

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
  if (prevProps.value !== this.props.value) { // check if a new value was passed
    this.checkTypeAhead(this.props.value);
  }
}
```

---

In your specific case where the parent does not do any processing of the `value` you could just directly use the `e.target.value`. The original suggestion allows you more flexibility though.

```
this.props.onChange(e.target.value);
this.checkTypeAhead(e.target.value);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am new in React and got confused in parent child relationship.Thank you very much.

I have one more doubt.May I ask please ?

Comment: Is it okay to set default props as shown below in Child:


`    static defaultProps = {
        typeaheadItems: null,
        lookupKey: null
    }; 
`
As I have already written ,if else conditions ? Like if I will not pass the props from parent it will just send the value to parent !

Answer (score 0):

You might need to change your function like below:

```
onInputChange(target) {
    console.log('target obj:', target);  // also try to log what you get 
    this.setState({ value: target.value });
}
```

By logging the `target` object parameter, you can find how you can get the user typed value, and then pass it to the state object.